# How does "magic" work in Marvel comics?

Tags: marvel, magic

I started reading comics about a year ago. Mutants are cool, time traveling is awesome.

But how about "magic"? I'm talking about Doctor Strange, Scarlet Witch, Pixie, Magik, and the like. Strange and Scarlet are even tier-one powerful characters.

Where is the source of their power? Is there a in-universe scientific explanation for them?

Comment: Are you asking "why is there magic" or "how does the magic work"? Or both?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm asking how does magic work. Let me edit the title.

Comment: And by "scientific" do you mean an in-world explanation?

Comment: the Ancient One in the Dr. Strange movie had a decent in-universe pseudo-scientific explanation

Comment: By scientific, I mean physics, biology, computer programming, modern study. Not necessary in-world, because Marvel universe itself is a fiction world, right?

Comment: You unfortunately cannot ask for real-world explanations as that's [off-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here, however, you *can* ask about in-world scientific explanations.

Comment: I did not ask for real-world explaination. I think there is a misunderstanding of "in-world" from me. I assume in-world = real-world. It seems that in-world means fiction-world. Right?

Comment: Yes. In-world or in-universe refers to within the fictional story. Real-world or out-of-universe is the opposite.

Comment: In the case of Dr. Strange (movie version), it is somehow because we live in an era of technology and science that gives us an illusion of fully understanding the reality that makes him a top Tier 1 character: he knows secret truths that are hidden to most of us. Strange first meeting with the Ancient is something like "you believe you know the truth, dumbass? Here is the red pill, Alice".

Comment: I mean, most of the superpowers in Marvel could reasonably be described as “magic” in some sense or another.

Comment: If anything, __I don't think this question is off-topic__. I think it's too broad, because there might be loads of characters that use magic in the Marvel universe. And what do you consider magic, anyway? Are Asgardians magical?

Comment: Yes, Thor and his family are sorcerers to me. I don't read Thor, does he also draw his power from someone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Marvel comics mainstream universe, magic is a real thing. People use it because it's there and because they can, just like any other ability or source of power.

The source of magic user's power depends on the magic user. Typically, there is no non-magical explanation for their powers. Magic, as a force, exists in the Marvel universe, and different characters have access to it in different ways. Certain scientifically-minded characters consider magic to *be* a science, just a kind of science we don't otherwise understand, but they never claim to have a "mundane" explanation for it using known science. (Reed Richards and Doctor Doom are two scientists who have studied magic; Doom is himself a sorcerer.)

In most cases, magic used by humans is actually drawn from other, extra-dimensional beings. Doctor Strange, for example, draws his magic primarily from the Vishanti, who are three elder god-like beings that grant him power in exchange for service. He has also, on occasion, drawn power from Dormammu (essentially a "demon") and other supernatural beings. Similarly, Scarlet Witch's Chaos Magic comes from the elder god Chthon.

There is also a level of ambient magical energy in each person, and in the universe as a whole. Certain characters can manipulate that energy. Scarlet Witch's mutation, for example, would allow her to manipulate the ambient magical energy even without her Chaos Magic, though she would be very significantly weaker. Adam Warlock and probably Ororo Munroe (Storm) can also use magic this way. (Adam Warlock's magic is amplified quite a bit by the Infinity Gem he possesses.)

Comment: now that Disney owns it all....kinda sounds like the Force ;)

Comment: So... magic kinda sounds like magic?  Not really a surprise there =P

Comment: I had thought I read somewhere in a comic that Reed Richards believed that at least the "ambient" magic found in the comic universe emanated from Hyperspace.  This would at least be another "source" of magic.

Comment: @Steve-O: the Force isn’t magic! You just count the midichlorians.